# Upload photos the facebook graph with high resolution

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

The facebook graph API lets to allow photos to the wall, ok, but how to specify I'd want for those photos to be high quality

```
$access_token=$_SESSION['access_token'];

$graph_url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=".$access_token;

$args=array( 'message' => $description, 'url' => $im_url );
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
```

I'm using that code form which anyone can see message and url are the params sent as if these were set on an input right, could there be a possibility of adding a third param that specifies I'd like for the photos to be high quality?

Might this be the correct way:

```
    $args=array( 'message' => $description, 'quality' => "high", 'url' => $im_url );
```

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload a PNG version of the image. 
It looks like it's working fine with PNG, I've just tested it.